# how do I run/finish test stript in github action yml file?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions

in my react app I have scripts:

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"test:coverage": "yarn test --coverage --watchAll",

  // in my yml file:
  - name: Yarn install, Build and Test
    run: |
      yarn 
      yarn test:coverage
      yarn build
```

how do I quit watch mode when the test is finished? because in github actions when it runs it just hangs in there infinite time.

Comment: You should just remove the `--watchAll` from the command, or use a different target in CI.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another command for local usage with `--watchAll`. Example:

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"test:coverage": "yarn test --coverage",
"test:coverage-watch": "yarn test:coverage --watchAll"
```